A problem from shift in the fermi energy level
if the effective mass of holes in a semiconductor is 5 times that of the electron, at what temperature would the fermi level shift by 15% from the middle of the forbidden energy band? (given that, eg = 1.20 ev.)
I attempted the problem and used
E_f = E_midgap + (3/4)ln(m_p*/m_e*)
And got 865 K .i asked the question to many person .some of them answered 865K,some answered 1730K.please tell me which one is correct.
